# Can't Delete Calendars

Tags: calendar

I'm having a bad time trying to delete a subscribed calendar. I am running OSX 10.8.4 on my iMac and IOS 6 on iPhone and iPad. Whenever I delete this calendar it reappears, usually within a few seconds. I have tried deleting from each device and from iCloud, without success. Any thoughts or suggestions would be most welcome.

Comment: Do those calendars belong to you (that is, did you create them) or are they subscribed calendars? Have you tried deleting them from https://www.icloud.com?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Jaume. I have clarified the question (see above) It is a subscribed calendar. And yes, I have repeatedly deleted it from my iCloud account, but it still returns.

Comment: What is the original source of the calender. ie Google calender, Mac calender, Outlook calender...others... ?

Comment: How are you trying to delete the subscribed calendar?

Comment: Thanks so much @Buscar and patrix for these responses. Original source of the subscribed calendar was iCal, it was created by me some years ago as a course calendar when I was an academic. I am now retired and the calendar is administered by my replacement at the university. I have repeatedly tried deleting the calendar (edit > delete) on each of my devices. I have tried switching off iCloud syncing of calendars on each device, deleting the calendar from iCloud, then renewing iCloud calendar sync. Nothing works!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you use iCal (not specified in your question), then the Subscribed calender should appear under subscriptions.

UN-checking them will stop showing them.

If you trying to completely remove them then Right Click on the calender and Delete in the Pop up.

[image]

---

If above fails lets do the "brutal" method:

1. First make an iCal backup:  Click on each calendar on the left hand side of iCal one at a time highlighting it's name and then going to File Export > Export and saving the resulting calendar file to a logical location for safekeeping.
2. Go to iCal > Quit iCal
3. Remove the following to the trash and restart your computer:

> Home > Library > Caches > com.apple.ical
>
> Home > Library > Calendars > Calendar Cache, Cache, Cache 1, 2, 3,
>   etc. (Do not remove Sync Cache or Theme Cache if present)

Launch iCal and test.

If the issue still persists at this point:

Remove the following to the trash and restart your computer:

> Home > Library > Caches > com.apple.ical
>
> Home > Library > Calendars > Calendar Cache, Cache, Cache 1, 2, 3,
>   etc. (**Do not remove Sync Cache or Theme Cache if present**)
>
> Home > Library > Preferences > com.apple.ical (There may be more than
>   one of these. Remove them all.)

---NOTE: Removing these files may remove any shared (CalDAV) calendars you may have access to. You will have to re-add those calendars to iCal > Preferences > Accounts.

Comment: Thanks, Buscar, for this detailed information. I have tried the normal deletion method, with a few tweaks (see my comment above) and will now proceed to your 'brutal' method with the cache files. I have no other shared or subscribed calendars — in retirement, I am pleased to be able to manage on my Personal calendar only. Will let you know whether it works. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same problem getting rid of old calendars. They kept popping back on. I figured that all of my electronics were back feeding each other. I got the iCloud calendar on my monitor, the calendars on my laptop, iPad and phone all displayed. Then I deleted one calendar from each of them as fast as I could. Then I took the next one and deleted it in sequence as fast as I could. They are gone and have not reappeared. I hope this works for others.